# Rails joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have three models

- `Tag` => `:id`, `:name`
- `Tagging` => `:id`, `:tag_id`, `:post_id`
- `Post` => `:id`, `:summary`

I know the id of the tag. I would like to query for all of the posts that have a specific `tag_id`, through the `Taggings` model.

Something like

```
@post = Post.joins(:taggings).where(:tag_id => 17)
```

but this doesn't work because it is looking for the tag_id in the `Post` model and not the `Tagging` model.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: have you set on the Post model the following `has_many :tags, :through => :tagging` ?

Comment: Using the `.where` format you can pass a string like `.where("taggings.tag_id = ?", 17)` to qualify the joined taggings table.

Comment: @tharrison perfect, thanks! If you post an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the .where format you can pass a string like .where("taggings.tag_id = ?", 17) to qualify the joined taggings table.

Answer (score 17):

I don't like to use string in ActiveRecord queries, so, I prefer this sintax:

```
@post = Post.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: {tag_id: 17})
```

Comment: You could also add additional conditions after taggings if needed `.where(taggings: {tag_id: 17},  tags: {valid: true})`

Answer (score 7):

First of all :

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, :through => :taggings 
 end

 class Taggins < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :post 
   belongs_to :tag
 end

 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :taggings 
   has_many :posts, :through => :taggings 
 end
```

If you have the tag object you can do

```
 @posts = @tag.posts
```

or

```
 class Post < .... 
   ....
   def self.find_by_tag_id(tag_id)
      Post.joins(:taggings).where('taggings.tag_id = ?', tag_id)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tharrison mentioned. A solution is:

```
@post = Post.joins(:taggings).where("taggings.tag_id = ?", 17)
```

Comment: Just a note here - the first 'taggings' needs to be singular, otherwise you will get the error: `association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association` Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association