# association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller

```
@post = Post.joins(:customers).select("customers.*,posts.*").find params[:id]
```

My post model

```
belongs_to :customer
```

My customer model

```
has_many :posts
```

And i am getting error as

```
Association named 'customers' was not found on Post; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

This is my controller output:

```
Processing by PostsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 113ms

ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Association named 'customers' was not found on Post; perhaps you misspelled it?):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This is a typical typo error:

```
@post = Post.joins(:customers).select("customers.*,posts.*").find params[:id]
# should be:
@post = Post.joins(:customer).select("customers.*,posts.*").find params[:id]
                          #^^ no plural
```

Because you defined the relation like this (using singular):

```
# Post model
belongs_to :customer
```

---

Some stuff to know:

- In the `joins`/`includes` method, always use the exact same name as the relation
- In the `where` clauses, always use the pluralized name of the relation (actually, the table's name, which is by default the model name in plural but can also be manually set)

Examples:

```
# Consider these relations:
User has_many :posts
Post belongs_to :user

# Usage of joins/includes & where:
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { name: 'BlogPost #1' })
                  #^            ^
Post.joins(:user).where(users: { name: 'Little Boby Table' })
              #^^           ^
```

---

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)

Comment: Ok now i need another clarification. I have `created_at` at both table. I need both dates(i.e) `Registration Date` and `Post Date` How can i get it.

Comment: This is another question that is not related to this one, create another question on Stackoverflow if you want. (but usually you use `post.created_at` to get the created_at value of a Post instance)

Comment: Why couldn't Rails be non-pluralized in all cases by default? No more pluralization errors..