# How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

If I have a model `Person`, which `has_many` `Vehicles` and each `Vehicle` can be of type `car` or `motorcycle`, how can I query for all persons, who have cars and all persons, who have motorcycles?

I don't think these are correct:

```
Person.joins(:vehicles).where(vehicle_type: 'auto')
Person.joins(:vehicles).where(vehicle_type: 'motorcycle')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
Person.includes(:vehicles).where(vehicles: { vehicle_type: 'auto' })
Person.includes(:vehicles).where(vehicles: { vehicle_type: 'motorcycle' })
```

---

Be careful with `.joins` and `.includes`:

```
# consider these models
Post # table name is posts
  belongs_to :user
                #^^
User # table name is users
  has_many :posts
               #^

# the `includes/joins` methods use the relation name defined in the model:
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { title: 'Bobby Table' })
                  #^            ^
# but the `where` uses the exact table name:
Post.includes(:user).where(users: { name: 'Bobby' })
                #^^^           ^
```

---

A tricky one:

```
Post
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
User # table named users
  has_many :posts

Post.includes(:author).where(users: { name: 'John' })
# because table is named users
```

---

Alternatively, the gem [activerecord_where_assoc](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) can achieve this (and much more):

```
Person.where_assoc_exists(:vehicles, vehicle_type: 'auto')
```

---

**Similar questions:**

- [association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association/19231664#19231664)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)
- [Rails: Finding all Users whose relationship has a specified attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210569/rails-finding-all-users-whose-relationship-has-a-specified-attribute/25210625#25210569)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need a clarification. You say: "the `includes/joins` methods use the name defined in the model", but in the second example you write `Post.includes(:user)`. Don't you mean that pluralization in `includes/joins` depends on the relationship of the two models?

Comment: @AlexPopov The pluralization in `includes/joins` depends on the name of the association defined in the model. If it was defined as `belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'`, you would have to use the relation's name: `.includes(:owner)`