# .where attribute of nested attribute attribute = string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to calculate the percentage of body groups for all injuries, but can't figure it out.

Injury model:

```
class Injury < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :season
  has_one :injury_type
end
```

InjuryType model:

```
class InjuryType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :body_group
end
```

BodyGroup model (no association):

```
class BodyGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I print the total number of injuries like this:

```
= Injury.all.order('start_date ASC').count
```

...**but then I'm stuck**. In my mind this should be super simple, something like:

```
= Injury.where(injury_type.body_group_id => 1).count
```

How can I print the number of injuries where body group has id 1? What am I doing wrong? I've tried this:

```
= Injury.joins(:body_group => :injury_type).where(:body_group => {:id => 1} )
```

...but this only gives me `#<Injury::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff14c929bf0>`, which I can't turn into a .count or a .sum.

Comment: you should use the table's name in the `where` clause, and the relation name in the `includes`/`joins` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352 and the similar questions linked in this answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probability looking for an association like the below:

```
class Injury < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :injury_type
end

class InjuryType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :body_group
  has_many :injuries
end

class BodyGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :injury_types
end
```

In this way, you can simplify the query:

```
Injury.joins(:injury_type).where(body_group_id: 1).count
```

Comment: Doesn't this then require InjuryType to have an injury_id, meaning a new InjuryType for every Injury?

Comment: If I add those associations and use your edited snippet, it results in `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column injury_types.injury_id does not exist`

Comment: It should be: 'An `injury` belongs to an `injury type` (assuming that there's a column for that). And an `injury_type` has many `injuries` obviously'. You can have 20 injuries which are broken bones for instance.

Comment: @Fietsband: I totally agree ;) @Ix Techau can you explain the association between `injury` and `injury_type`

Comment: Ok, those associations make more sense. I've changed them so it's now: Injury belongs_to InjuryType, and InjuryType has_many Injuries. If I now do `Injury.joins(injury_type: :body_group).where("body_groups.id = 1").count`, it doesn't break but it's always 0. If I do a :pluck, the array is empty.

Comment: you need to fix the association between `InjuryType` and `BodyGroup` as well