# Writing a simple SQL query in Rails 3.2 with multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to write a SQL query in Rails 3.2 syntax that says:

"*Give me all Submissions with missions that belong to a track where `visibility_private == false`*"

```
Track.rb
   has_many :missions
   attr_accessible :visibility_private

Mission.rb
   belongs_to :track
   has_many :submissions

Submission.rb
   belongs_to :mission
```

My initial attempt was this, but that's definitely wrong:

```
Submission.joins(:mission).where(:missions => { mission.track.visibility_private == false })
```

Comment: My initial attempt was this, but that's definitely wrong:

`Submission.joins(:mission).where(:missions => { mission.track.visibility_private == false })`

Comment: Try `Submission.joins(:mission, :track).where(:mission => { :track => { visibility_private: false } })`

Comment: Maybe this Q/A can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352

Comment: Im getting `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'track' was not found on Submission; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Try this: `Submission.includes(mission: :track).where(tracks: { visibility_private: false })`

Comment: Got it! It was this: `Submission.joins(:mission => :track).where(:tracks => { :visibility_private => false })`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like,

```
Submission.joins(mission: :track).where("tracks.visibility_private = ?",false)
```

or

```
Submission.joins(mission: :track).where(tracks: { visibility_private: false })
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Submission.includes(mission: :track).where(tracks: { visibility_private: false })
```