# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause — Searching with two models Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have a searchbar on my landing page where I can search for books from users from different universities. It doesn't seem to accept the .joins when it gets redirected to the Book Index Page. Book belongs to user and user has many books.

I always get:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"

BooksController.rb

```
def index
  if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
  @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(user: {university: params[:users][:university]}).uniq
  end
end
```

PagesController.rb

```
def home
  @books = Book.new
end
```

And this is my search in simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@books], url: books_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Title", label: false %></li>
    <%= simple_fields_for :users do |r| %>
      <li><%= r.input :university, placeholder: "University", label: false %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'search', class: "btn"  %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :users
end
```

Full error is:

> LINE 1: ... "books"."user_id" WHERE "books"."title" = $1 AND "user"."un...
>                                                                ^
>   : SELECT DISTINCT "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "books"."user_id" WHERE "books"."title" = $1 AND "user"."university" = $2>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `where` method expects to receive the **exact table name** (see full example here: [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)):

```
@books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
@books = @books.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]}).uniq
#                     ^ relation name  ^ exact name of the table
```

If, for some reason, the name of the table storing the `User` records was named `utilisateurs`, then the `where` usage would be:

```
@books = Book.joins(:user).where(utilisateurs: { name: 'Bob' })
```

Comment: Thanks for that information! Now i know. this works great

Answer (score 1):

Try using the plural form of the relationship with user to query by the university, like:

```
Book.where('title = ?', params[:book][:title])
    .joins(:user)
    .where(users: { university: params[:users][:university] }).uniq
```

Comment: Can you add an 's' to params[:user][:university].  so it's like params[:users][:university]. because that works! thank you :)

Comment: try this `Book.joins(:user).where("books.title = ? and users.university = ?" , params[:book][:title], params[:users][:university]).uniq`

Comment: The `where` method needs to receive the *exact table name*, it may not be the plural version of the relation. If the `User` record is linked to the table named `utilisateurs` (french), then in the where you would use `Book.joins(:user).where(utilisateurs: { name: 'bob' })`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to provide `.includes(:user)` before filtering with `where` to avoid `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table`