# Rails ActiveRails joins - table name in plural/singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join, activerecord

I have the following "Query" using ActiveRecord:

```
Product.joins(product_attr_vals: [attr_val: [:attr]])
       .joins(:product_model)
       .where(product_models: {id: @product_model.id}, attrs: {id: attr.id})
       .distinct
       .count
```

I am not being able to understand why sometimes, in `joins()`, rails accept the table name in plural and others in singular.

- `product_attr_vals:` **(does not work if in singular -> product_attr_val)**
- `attr_val:`
- `:attr`
- `:product_model`

---

Some info:

*models/product_model_attr_val.rb*

```
class ProductModelAttrVal < ApplicationRecord
  validates :product_model_id, uniqueness: { scope: :attr_val_id }

  belongs_to :product_model
  belongs_to :attr_val
end
```

*db/migrate/db_creation.rb*

```
create_table :product_model_attr_vals do |t|
  t.references :product_model, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.references :attr_val, null: false, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352 (`joins`/`includes`/`preload` vs `where`: when to use relation name and when to use table's name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to when to use singular or plural lies in the name of the association. Usually `has_many` associations are named in plural, whereas `belongs_to` associations are named in singular. Behind the scenes when building the query ActiveRecord will make sure to always use the right table name (plural). In Rails there is the concept of "convention over configuration", which means a lot of stuff have a predefined approach that will work out of the box. E.g. take an association `belongs_to :product`. ActiveRecord will look for a column `product_id` in the table `products` and use it to load the product. Another example, `has_many :products` - ActiveRecord will look for a table called `products` and assume it has a column `your_model_id`. Thus it will load all the products for you model instance.

Back to your question, when to use singular or plural. If you are not sure, check your association definition in the respective model. In general, `has_many` associations use plural, `belongs_to` associations use singular. Here is an example with two models:

```
class Employee
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

And here are some `joins` examples:

```
Employee.joins(:tasks) # plural due to has_many 
Task.joins(:employee) # singular due to belongs_to
```

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your outstanding answer! I was going crazy thinking I had done something wrong.