# Rails: Finding all Users whose relationship has a specified attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rosterplayers
  has_many :rosters, -> { uniq } ,  :through => :rosterplayers
end

class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rosterplayers
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :rosterplayers
end

class Rosterplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :roster_id }
end
```

The Rosterplayer table has three columns: `user_id`, `roster_id,` and `pending` (boolean)

**Question**: Given a roster, how would I retrieve all users that are currently pending?

**Attempt**: My first attempt was to loop through all the users in the roster:

```
@team.rosters[0].users.each do |u|
  Rosterplayer.find_by(roster_id: rosters[0].id, user_id: u.id, pending: true)
end
```

But I feel like there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: show `pending?` method

Comment: I fixed my above post to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achivete this by doing the following:

```
User.includes(:rosterplayers).where(rosterplayers: { pending: true })
```

This will return all User records having at least 1 `rosterplayer` having `pending` set to `true`.

Limit the query to a specific `roster` instance:

```
User.includes(:rosterplayers).where(rosterplayers: { pending: true, roster_id: your_roster_id })
# your_roster_id can actually be an array of IDs
```

---

**Additional note:** Be carefull with .joins and .includes:

```
# consider these models
Post 
  belongs_to :user
                #^^
User
  has_many :posts
               #^

# the `includes/joins` methods use the name defined in the model :
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { title: 'Bobby Table' })
                  #^            ^
# but the `where` uses the pluralized version (table's name) : 
Post.includes(:user).where(users: { name: 'Bobby' })
                #^^^           ^
```

---

**Similar questions:**

- [association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association/19231664#19231664)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Comment: Given that Users can be on many Rosters, how would I also limit the query to one specified roster (i.e. `team.rosters[0]`)?

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your requirement. It is a simple `where` clause added to the query