# Finding all users with specific attribute in a through relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

See the details below to make sense.

I am trying to write a line of code that will be searching the database and show the users that have a specific skill.

My clue is that I should be using something like `@user.where('skill = ?', skillvariable)`  or a specific query. Any point/guidance to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

**Details**:

I have a users model, a skills model and a user_skills model.

In user.rb I have the relation `has_many :skills, through: :user_skills`.

In the skill.rb I have the relations `has_many :user_skills` and `has_many :users, through: :user_skills`,

and then in user_skills.rb I have the `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :skill`.

The user_skills schema is:

```
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "skill_id"
```

And the skills schema is:

```
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "slug"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
User.includes(:skills).where(skills: { name: 'Archery' })
```

This will letterally:

> Retrieve all users having at least one skill named 'archery'.

---

**Similar questions:**

- [association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association/19231664#19231664)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)
- [Rails: Finding all Users whose relationship has a specified attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210569/rails-finding-all-users-whose-relationship-has-a-specified-attribute/25210625#25210569)