# Multiple Left join with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to request some data with ActiveRecord with no success.

I have these models :

*Sections* have multiple *Questions*

*Questions* have one *Answer*

One *Answer* belongs to one *User* and one *Question*

So I would like request for a specified user, all Sections with linked Questions et linked Answer.

Maybe something like

```
Section.all.joins(:questions).joins(:answer).where(answer.user_id = USER_ID)
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Section.joins(questions: :answer).where(answers: { user_id: USER_ID })
```

---

Some stuff to know:

- In the `joins`/`includes` method, always use the exact same name as the relation
- In the `where` clauses, always use the pluralized name of the relation (actually, the table's name, which is by default the model name in plural but can also be manually set)

Examples:

```
# Consider these relations:
User has_many :posts
Post belongs_to :user

# Usage of joins/includes & where:
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { name: 'BlogPost #1' })
                  #^            ^
Post.joins(:user).where(users: { name: 'Little Boby Table' })
              #^^           ^
```

---

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [association named not found perhaps misspelled issue in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231629/association-named-not-found-perhaps-misspelled-issue-in-rails-association/19231664#19231664)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Comment: If you have again a few minutes.

Can you explain this :  questions: :answer

Why first colon is a the end and the second one at the beginning ?

Comment: it is the new ruby hash syntax. It is exactly the same to use `{ :questions => :answer }` and `{ questions: :answer }` (key is a symbol, value is a symbol in both examples). (The new syntax has been integrated to Ruby 1.9.x and newer versions

Comment: It seems it only returns the first Section.

Is it possible to user a left join for, the Answer join ?

Comment: Because, if there is not Answer. The request will return nothing

Comment: use `includes` instead of the `joins` and the Section without answer(s) should be displayed

Comment: You get a +1 for Little Boby table, though I believe it was Little Bobby Drop Tables?